# how to customize :active link color for only for one menu item in WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I've added book-table class for the last menu item and tried to customize it. The main trouble is that hover works default mode works but when it's active and you are locating on that specific page active color doesn't work. It extends default active link color which is for other menu items. Here is the code:

```
.book-table {
background-color:#e67e22;
color: #ffffff;
border: 2px solid;
border-color: #e67e22;
    line-height: 3.5;
    border-radius:40px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;

}

.book-table:hover {
background-color: #ff8214;
border: 2px solid;
border-color: #ff8214;
    line-height: 0;
    border-radius:40px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;

}

.book-table a:hover,
.book-table a:focus,
.book-table a:active {
    color: #222222 !important
}
.book-table > li > li.current-menu-item > a {
    color: #fff

 }
```

Is there any way to change active color only for this latest menu link?

Comment: provide html markup. I think, your problem is with '>'

Comment: Indeed...an `li` **cannot** have another `li` as a *direct descendant*.

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan if problem was with HTML then hover will not work as well but as I said hover works.

Comment: @Paulie_D I know that this code is wrong however is there any way to solve described issue?

Comment: your rule added here '.book-table > li > li.current-menu-item > a' have some wrong parts!!!

Comment: @Artyom provide html markup, if you want to get help. we can't guess how your page is rendering